# Wordpress - Custom Post Type and Custom Permalink Structures Error

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have 3 custom post types setup and I have created a custom permalink structure for each. The problem I am having is that the third custom post type I have setup with the custom permalink, is being used for the previous 2.

Example:

- Classified
- Employment
- Sponsorship

The above are the post types and I have the custom permalink structure set to (for each):
/post_type/post_id/

Now, The above order are the order they are set in and sponsorship takes over all of them. So for instance:

```
/classified/100/
/employment/101/
/sponsorship/102/
```

The above all use the permalink:

```
/sponsorship/100/
/sponsorship/101/
/sponsorship/102/
```

What am I doing wrong to get this error happening? Is it a permalink structure error? below is my code I am using to create the custom permalink structures for each. The only difference is that %c_id% is changed to %e_id% and %s_id% for classifieds, employment and sponsorship. And also any reference to 'classifieds' is changed to employment and sponsorship respectively.

```
add_action('init', 'classifieds_rewrite');
function classifieds_rewrite() {
    global $wp_rewrite;

    $queryarg = 'post_type=classifieds&p=';
    $wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag('%c_id%', '([^/]+)', $queryarg);
    $wp_rewrite->add_permastruct('classifieds', '/classifieds/%c_id%/', false);
}

add_filter('post_type_link', 'classifieds_permalink', 1, 3);
function classifieds_permalink($post_link, $id = 0) {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $post = &get_post($id);
    if ( is_wp_error( $post ) )
        return $post;
    $newlink = $wp_rewrite->get_extra_permastruct('classifieds');
    $newlink = str_replace("%c_id%", $post->ID, $newlink);
    $newlink = home_url(user_trailingslashit($newlink));
    return $newlink;
}
```

Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you registered 3 different post types and you are trying to rewrite each post type so their slug precedes the post id. To start with just the slug of each post type, it doesn't seem like you are issuing the rewrite when you register each post type, is this correct? If not, you can take care of this part by adding the following with the other arguments when registering each post type.

```
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'classified', 'with_front' => true )
```

Additional reference with extensive permalink rewrites here: http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/wordpress-permalink-add

Comment: I have:

`'rewrite' => true`

??

Comment: If you use `'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'YourSlug', 'with_front' => true )` it will rewrite your permalinks for your posts with the slug you specify. For example if you put `'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'classified', 'with_front' => true )` for your classified posts, your links will be rewritten to www.yoursite.com/classified/your-post-title depending on the additional permalink structure you have set in your WP admin.

Comment: Yeah, but I need to use the post_id for the second part of the URL. So it needs to be /classifieds/124/ rather than /classifieds/the-title-here/

Is there any way to that by default? Because I want the other pages on the site to be able to /about/ and /contact/ etc...?

Comment: I see. Not sure if this is leading to your problem but in the following blog post about custom rewrites, it advises that 'rewrite' should be set to false if doing custom rewrites outside of the default arguments: http://www.johnpbloch.com/2010/08/custom-post-types-and-better-permalinks/

Comment: OK, thanks for that! I got it working, in terms of getting it all working in the admin, I just get 404 error messages on the pages when I try to go to them.

Comment: Basically I have got the the front end working in terms of permalinks, and all the pages go to where they should be, it's just the admin under the post title that doesn't show the correct URL. So not sure what sort of impact that will have. When calling the permalink function, it generates the URL issue I was explaining in my first post, but other than that, it's fine :)